# 403 creating a folder via Google-Drive-RESTAPI v3

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a folder using the Google-Drive REST-API. My problem ist the respond 'Insufficient Permission'.

I'm using the sample code directly from the GDrive-API Documentation. But it does not work.

```html
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), createDir);
});


/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
}

function createDir(auth) {
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    var fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'Invoice',
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    };
    drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        fields: 'id'
    }, function (err, file) {
        if (err) {
            // Handle error
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Folder Id: ', file.id);
        }
    });
}
```

NOTE: Reading files works without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the wrong access scope. Use 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' for full access.